# how to save the datetime in datagrid as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using `DataGridView` in WinForms,
i am using the sql server database
 and I am using the smalldatetime as datatype, but it is accepting the date as `mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss AM`.

How to save that in:
`dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM AM` format
i am little bit confused here how to change the format as by the designer the specified dd/mm/yyyy format is not available

Comment: What database are you saving it too?

Comment: I guess `DateTime` is the datatype for the `DataGridView` and to control the format of display of the dates you should set `DefaultCellStyle,.Format` of the required column to `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` (Captial M is for months and small m for minutes)

Comment: neil i am saving it to sql server

Comment: vendetta, can you wirte the full code, i am a newbie i dont know properties.

Comment: It was just a guess, you need to add information about what control is accepting your datetime input or you just want to display that in the format specified, any validations you are performing for the format. Edit the question and add some relevant parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-AU"))
```

By using culture info you can set different format...

Comment: Where you are linking the items to datagridview. I do not know about your data structure. It would be nice if you prove what else you want to display in datagridview

Comment: i just only want to convert the date time format of smalldatetime into the specified format

Comment: From where you are getting DateTime object?

Comment: i am not getting the object i am saving the value of date from the textbox

Comment: let suppose you have textBox1 and you want to display datetime. Then this line of code will work for you: textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-AU")). If you want more help then kindly write more details.

Comment: sir my doubt is not that, you have given the textbox.text right?
and then if i want to save that text to the database then in the datecolumn i am using the smalldatetime as a data type but that smalldatetime is accepting only the mm/dd/yyyy
i want to show that datagrid to the user, so the column should be in the format
dd/mm/yyyy
now you got whats my problem is

Comment: Format is depend upon the culutureinfo and you have to modify the regional setting to get this format without making any change in your code. You can fix it in "Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region". If you will select the country Australia then you will get same format you want to show. I do not have any experience with sql, So I can not provide you specific solution.

Comment: thank you sir. a very much thanks to you, have solved my biggest problem without code
:)

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;     // Use current time
string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy";      // Use this format
string myDateTime = time.ToString(format));  // Write to console
```

You can make any format, just set the format variable using following conditions depending on your need.

```
MMM     display three-letter month
ddd     display three-letter day of the WEEK
d       display day of the MONTH
HH      display two-digit hours on 24-hour scale
mm      display two-digit minutes
yyyy    display four-digit year
M       display one-digit month number
d       display one-digit day of the MONTH
h       display one-digit hour on 12-hour scale
mm      display two-digit minutes
yy      display two-digit year
```

for more examples and formats [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).